# Is there any option to follow a user?

Tags: support, users

I'm very new here, and I have already found some people, who write good answers. I want to follow them. Like to watch their work in free time.

Is there any option to follow a user?

Answer (score 6):

Every user has an RSS feed of their activity, which you can find at the bottom of the [Activity tab of their profile page](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/98685/newton?tab=topactivity):

[image]

There is no other way to be notified of their activity within the Stack Exchange network (e.g. via inbox notifications). You'll need an RSS reader to consume this feed.

Comment: Ubiquitous RSS feeds offered by every SE site in the era when others were dropping their RSS/Atom support in favor of consolidated social media garbage posts was one of the major factors that made me stay with Stack Exchange. RSS just saves a lot of time and allows to stay focused and I really hope SE/SO won't drop its support in the near future.