# How do I speak privately with a poster

Tags: discussion

How do I speak privately with a poster who has more questions than would be appropriate for the site? Should I just list my email address, or is this too public?

Comment: There is a chat option. When the comments get too long, the chat option automatically appears. I think you can discuss these types of questions in Chemistry Meta rather.

Comment: @M. Farooq: The OP has a rep of 1. You need 20 to chat. is there any other way?

Comment: I honestly didn't expect a user with >10k to post this on main site and ignore both CSE's and mother Metas. [How do I contact other users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57537); [Any way to send a personal message to another user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431)

Comment: "And you may ask yourself, 'Well... how did I get here?'"

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4838/is-there-any-option-to-follow-a-user?r=SearchResults

Comment: I have more than 10k rep and am confused. This seems to be intentional (from a comment in one of the quoted meta questions): "What I really REALLY dislike is that it takes every user a lot of time to find out that this feature does intentionally not exist. My first thought never was "well, let's see if I even can send a PM"; my first thought just was "Okay, I want to send a PM; where do I have to click?" And then I went on searching for the presumed hidden button. And didn't find it. And didn't. And got frustrated. And only much later I thought about searching for the topic on Meta. ."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How do I speak privately with a poster who has more questions than would be appropriate for the site?

Some users leave information in their profile on how to reach them off-platform. There generally is no way to do anything privately on Stack Exchange, except for serious moderation issues.

Please see the links provided by andselisk for more detail:

- [How do I contact other users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57537/260760)
- [Any way to send a personal message to another user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/431/260760)

> Should I just list my email address, or is this too public?

I have a friend that said: It's just an email address, I can have another one tomorrow. That's one opinion. If you are of the same opinion, then you can try that. There is a high chance it'll get flagged and removed when seen.

As moderators we have to care for [personally identifiable information (PII)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_data) and even if it is given up voluntarily and with intend we might just delete it to be safe anyway as it could have been accidental.

To answer your question: You probably shouldn't post your email address as it is very public.